# Extending an already defined component in react

Tags: reactjs, components

I've got a component named `Button` in a react library and would like to extend its capabilities furthermore. The following is the code which I wrote.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

export class Button extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
          <Button color="primary" className="Button">primary</Button>
        );
    }

}
```

I would like to use the same name as the already defined component. The problem is, when I run the application, I get an error saying,

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: C:/Users/dimal/Documents/GitHub/theme-wso2/module/components/MaterialButton.js: Duplicate declaration "Button"
```

How can I import the component I would like to extend in another name? as far as I think, if I rename the component this issue would go away! Am I correct?

Comment: From the React docs: "At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies. Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way."  - https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: This is the correct answer, actually. Create a brand new component if you have to. Making a component inheritance hierarchy is just going to cause problems later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name your `Button` from `reactstrap` to a diff name. To achieve this write something similar to below

```
import { Button as BootStrapButton } from 'reactstrap';
```

Now use `BootStrapButton` in places where you want to use `button` from `reactstrap`.

Comment: This does what OP is asking to be able to do, but OP shouldn't do what OP is asking.